# SSIS file task system to copy multiple input files from different source paths to different destination paths

Tags: ssis, file-copying, foreach-loop-container

I have to copy files from source to destination, here the tricky part is, i have many source files located in different shared paths, i need to copy those input files to particular destination folders.

For Example:
Spath1/a.txt -->  Dpath1/, spath2/b.txt -->  Dpath2/,  spath3/c.txt -->  Dpath3/, Etc..

Can i use a table to map the input files/source paths and destination folder and use foreach loop to attain the solution?

kindly post your suggestsions.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO Harun

Yes, you can use a table in this case. First add an an object-type variable to the package, let's call it @folders and a second string-type variable, lets call this as @currentSrc and lastly third string-variable we call @currentDst. Then add Execute SQL task to get the list of folders. Set the result set to "Full result set" and add a reference to @folders-variable in the Result Set tab.

Add a For Each loop, set the Enumerator as "Foreach ADO Enumerator", @folders as the ADO object source variable and "Rows in the first table" as Enumeration mode. Add a reference to @currenSrc and @currenDst-variables in the "Variable Mappings" tab.

Now you can use the File System Task to copy files from sources to destinations based on the data you have on a table in the database (make sure to reference @currentSrc and @currentDst variables in the File System task).